# How to display custom map service on android mapview?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

How can i add my own map tile server with OSM and display it on android mapview, URL Example : http://abc/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?

Glad if i also know how to apply markers, polylines, polygons on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid).

[How to use the osmdroid library](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library) already covers lots of the things you asked for.

[Creating a custom tile provider chain](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources#creating-a-custom-tile-provider-chain) explains how to use your own tile server.

Comment: osmdroid project from github has many sub projects are too complex, i went through this blog _https://www.thiengo.com.br/openstreetmap-no-android-iniciando-com-marker-e-gps?fb_comment_id=570619459703998_1349485955150674&comment_id=1349485955150674#f1ec048e73d4e1c_ I followed the instructions and saw an empty tile with markers & zoom buttons on my emulator without map

Comment: Try to stick to the official documentation.